# How to use JMeter HTTP request by using VPN

Tags: automation, jmeter, vpn

I am trying to access the Webpage that only accessible in Browser when i am connected through VPN but when I am sending the Request from JMeter by using the HTTP Request Script it shows the error "Unauthorized" even when I am connected with VPN still I am getting same error.

Also I try the Http Proxy server option in the Advance tab section of Http Request and provide the VPN IP Address and Port Number and Username and Password but still I am unable to access the Url from JMeter.

Answer (score 0):

This is not due to vpn.
Check your request headers for token or authorization value.
You need to correlate that before moving ahead.
Please share complete request with header & cookies for more help.

Answer (score 0):

[Proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server) != [VPN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network), given your machine is connected to the VPN you should be able to access the application using JMeter's [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers without any extra configuration

With regards to your "Unauthorized", if it stands for [HTTP Status Code 401 - Unauthorized](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401) which means that you need to provide valid authorization context along with the request.

- If you're able to open the application using your browser without having to enter credentials, most probably the authorization is being performed via [SSO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on), in this case you need to add [HTTP Authorization Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager) and properly configure it for your application authentication flow, see [Windows Authentication with Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/windows-authentication-apache-jmeter) article for more details
- If you need to provide credentials and just trying to replay the recorded script - most probably you need to implement [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start): detect all dynamic parameters and replace recorded hard-coded values with the ones fetched from the previous responses using JMeter [Post-Processors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors)